# I want to use background image in my Angular login.Component.ts but that does not show

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, background-image

This is my html Div in which i want to use background image

```
<div class="bg-img">
<div class="container">
 <form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="panel panel-primary pb-3">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">Instrutors Login Form</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="pane-body">
      <div class="form-group ">
        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="username">User Name:</label>
        <div class="col-md-8">
          <input type="text" id="username" formControlName="username" class="form-control" ng-model="mymdl">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="password">Password:</label>
          <div class="col-md-8">
            <input type="password" id="password" formControlName="password" class="form-control">
          </div>
        </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <button type="submit">login</button> <p> <a routerLink="/register">Signup</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
</div>
```

This is my login.component.css file im using reference of class"bg-img" here to use image in background

```
    .bg-img{
    background-image: url('/src/assets/images/img1.jpg');

    }
```

Comment: Try `background-image: url('assets/images/img1.jpg')`.

Comment: Thanks Dear sir  ConnorsFan error resolved

Answer (score 1):

Your HTML is not valid:

This is how it starts:

```
<div class="bg-img">
<div class="container">
<form [formGroup]="loginForm" class="form-horizontal" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
```

And this is how it finishes:

```
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

Start by fixing that first. Also make sure none of the nested children have background colors set. You won't be able to see the full image of the outermost container if the inner ones have a set background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this from: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

```
/* Container holding the image and the text */
.container {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

/* Bottom left text */
.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

/* Top left text */
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

/* Top right text */
.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

/* Bottom right text */
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

<div class="container">
    <img src="../../../assets/images/DebraFacebook.jpg" alt="DebraFacebook" style="width:100%;">
    <div class="bottom-left">Bottom Left</div>
    <div class="top-left">Top Left</div>
    <div class="top-right">Top Right</div>
    <div class="bottom-right">Bottom Right</div>
    <div class="centered">Centered</div>
</div>
```